# Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable en Tableau con Tabpy

Tags: python, script, statsmodels

estoy usando la funcion de statsmodels SimpleExpSmoothing para ejecutarla en Tableau con Tabpy y me devuelve este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad es que no se muy bien como resolverlo, es la primera vez que utilizo statsmodels en tabpy

Comment: Hola Amigo, te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask], 
[mre], 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre